# Make image size responsive to container dimensions while maintaining its aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a max-height. It contains an image with a portrait aspect ratio. My goal is, that the image should adapt to the size of the container (getting max its height and max. it's width), without losing it's aspect ratio.

When I use `height: auto; width: 100%` on the image, the image gets larger than its parents `max-height`.

On the other hand, if I set `width: auto; height: 100%` on the image, it can get larger than its parents width.

And if I set `max-height: 50px; width: 100%;` it can get distorted, depending on its parents width.

```css
.container {
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/40x60.jpg" width="40" height="60"/>
</div>
```

Comment: _"On the other hand, if I set width: auto; max-height: 50px on the image, it doesn't adapt to the width of its parent."_ - why should it, when you said you wanted to _keep_ its aspect ratio?

Comment: What I wanted to point out is that the image can get larger than its parents width. It was just an attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe with CSS grid

```css
.container {
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  
  /* for the demo */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: auto;
}

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/40x60.jpg" width="40" height="60" >
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I was a little too quick. The img in the code snippet I posted is actually a SVG, which works perfectly in your solution. Unfortunately, it doesn't work with pixel images... Just try it with `https://placehold.co/40x60.jpg` as src attribute

Answer (score 0):

> May be we can reduce code of css

```css
.container
{
  max-height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: auto;
}

.container img
{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <img src="https://placehold.co/40x60.jpg" >
</div>
```